# How to return a Task implementing IAsyncActionFilter in F#?

Tags: c#, f#

it's me again

I'm implementing the IAsyncActionFilter interface and I have the following:

```fs
type UserExistsFilter =

    interface IAsyncActionFilter with

        member this.OnActionExecutionAsync(context: ActionExecutingContext, next: ActionExecutionDelegate) =
            let task = next.Invoke
            task
```

However I got the following error:

```fs
This expression was expected to have type 'Task' but here has type 'unit -> Task<ActionExecutedContext>'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: mabye let task = next.Invoke ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```fs
type UserExistsFilter =

    interface IAsyncActionFilter with

        member this.OnActionExecutionAsync(context: ActionExecutingContext, next: ActionExecutionDelegate) =
            async {
                let task = next.Invoke()
                return task
            }
            |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async#how-to-work-with-net-async-and-task

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
type UserExistsFilter =

    interface IAsyncActionFilter with

        member this.OnActionExecutionAsync(context: ActionExecutingContext, next: ActionExecutionDelegate) =
            task {
                let task = next.Invoke()
                return task
            }
```